# packet_write_wait: Connection to @host port 22: Broken pipe

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, scp

I'm trying to copy some files from production server(ubuntu 16.04) to backup server(ubuntu 16.04) using scp command but getting

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to @host port 22: Broken pipe
Lost connection
```

I have tried adding

```
-o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o ServerAliveCountMax=5
```

from
https://superuser.com/questions/1331240/packet-write-wait-connection-to-xxx-port-3591-broken-pipe
https://superuser.com/questions/1331240/packet-write-wait-connection-to-xxx-port-3591-broken-pipe
https://superuser.com/questions/1137584/packet-write-wait-broken-pipe-error-on-macos-sierra-ssh
but then its started throwing

```
Timeout, server @host not responding.
lost connection
```

I'm able to get the ssh connection to the backup server but not able to copy any files.
Point out something which I can do and copy files to backup server.Thanks in advance.

I found that I can copy files/folders upto 4k size to backup server but not bigger files. it's working when I'm trying to copy large files to another server but not on backup server.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I found fix by setting the LAN card's mtu setting to 1492 by

`# ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492`

Refer this link for more information : http://www.microhowto.info/howto/change_the_mtu_of_a_network_interface.html